# yii2-DynaGrid After changing attribute label, this column becomes hidden for all users

Tags: yii2-dynagrid

After changing class, header, label, or attribute.

Each user must go to "Personalize grid settings" and move this column to visible. I want to fix it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration

```php
$this->execute("UPDATE dynagrid SET data = REPLACE(data, '6d674618', 'cdb49d00') WHERE id LIKE 'your-grid-id%'");
```

`cdb49d00` - CRC32 hash key for new column label. [Online](https://md5calc.com/hash/crc32/Label_new) service to encode it.

`DynaGrid::getColumnKey()` - here you can see how Column Key is generated. `attribute/label/header/class`